# Random Number Help - I have a confidence, max, and min, how should I do this?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, statistics, random

For a class project, I need to create a list of 100 randomly simulated numbers, but I am struggling with the formula. According to the homework, I know that I am 95% confident that the range of the random numbers falls between x and y and follows a normal distribution. That's all I know. Despite feeling like it is missing information, I'm doing my best to work with what I have.

If I use the x and y as population of my data set, I am able to come up with a mean and SD and margin of error and therefore a range of values it can fall between. However, randbetweeen does not follow a normal distribution. When I use norminv, the values seem all over the place and hard coding a max and min would make it not follow a normal distribution.

Is there a way to combine these two formulas? Or is there a better way to calculate an SD between the range above to ensure 95% confidence so I can just use norminv?

Thanks!

Comment: [This may prove useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241784/generating-random-numbers-with-normal-distribution-in-excel)

Comment: While that is useful, that's where I am at right now. Issue is, norminv will not take into account the range I am looking for. I'm trying to overcome that.

Comment: I do think you were given enough information to use the norminv function. You need to think about what you are given and how to convert that into the inputs that the norminv function uses.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sheet with some results. See bellow:

[image: ScreenShot]

It may help you with your project. Additional information:

1. Input data - you can find in Cells F1 and F2 (I defined values 0,025 and 0,975, because of 95% of confidence, but not sure it is proper)
2. Formula in the column A (100 rows) - I am working with the 95% of confidence

```
=RAND()*($F$2-$F$1)*1,05+($F$1-($F$2-$F$1)*0,025
```

3. Formula in column B - Mean = 5 & Standard Deviation = 2

```
=NORM.INV(A1;5;2)
```

4. Cells F4 and F5 just checking min and max values in the column A
5. Cells F6 and F7 just checking number of values in the column A out of range of confidence

Hope, it is useful for you.

Best regards, Lukas